# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint (default-cli) on project sample-app

Tags: maven, jslint

I am trying to have js code check using Maven-Jslint Plugin. But when I am  trying to execute the following code its throwing an error.

```
    <profiles> 
        <profile> 
            <id>jslint</id> 
            <build> 
                <plugins> 
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                            <executions> 
                            <execution> 
                                <id>default-cli</id> 
                                <phase>test</phase> 
                                <goals> 
                                    <goal>test</goal> 
                                </goals> 
                                <configuration> 
                                    <jar>${jslint.jar}</jar> 
                                    <options>${jslint.options}</options> 
                                    <predef>${jslint.predef}</predef> 
                                    <sourceJsFolder>
                                    ${basedir}/src/main/js
                                    </sourceJsFolder>
                                </configuration> 
                            </execution> 
                        </executions> 
                    </plugin> 
                </plugins> 
            </build> 
        </profile> 
    </profiles> 
 </project>
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint (default-cli) on project sample-app: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint failed: charsetName -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint (default-cli) on project sample-app: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jslint-maven-plugin:1.0.1:jslint failed: charsetName

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Can any one of u please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old problem that I just ran across myself. This error happens if jslint reads the file using the wrong encoding. Try specifying the encoding property and setting it to `utf8` See below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jslint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions> 
        <execution> 
            <id>default-cli</id> 
            <phase>test</phase> 
            <goals> 
                <goal>test</goal> 
            </goals> 
            <configuration> 
                <jar>${jslint.jar}</jar> 
                <options>${jslint.options}</options> 
                <predef>${jslint.predef}</predef> 
                <sourceJsFolder>
                ${basedir}/src/main/js
                </sourceJsFolder>

                <!-- Sets the encoding of the js files beign read -->
                <encoding>utf8</encoding>
            </configuration> 
        </execution> 
    </executions> 
</plugin>
```